# SQL Server: Index columns used in select where column1 like str1 Or column2 like str2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MoneyTrans]
(
    [Trans_id] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    [Amount] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    [Currency] [nvarchar](11) NULL,
    [ExchangeRate] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    [CorrAmount] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    [senderName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [SenderPhone] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [RecipientName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [RecipientPhone] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [SenderPr] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [RecipientPr] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [Trans_Status] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    [SendDate] [nvarchar](12) NULL,
    [Receivdate] [nvarchar](12) NULL,
    [Trans_type] [nvarchar](25) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

and all queries look like either

```
SELECT * 
FROM MoneyTrans  
WHERE [senderName] = 'some one' OR [RecipientName] = 'some one'
```

or

```
SELECT * 
FROM MoneyTrans 
WHERE [SenderPhone] = '123456' OR [RecipientPhone] = '123456'
```

What is the best strategy for indexing?

Is it to use **covering indexes** like this

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ix_MoneyTrans_NamPhon] 
ON [dbo].[MoneyTrans] ([senderName] ASC, [RecipientName] ASC) 
INCLUDE ([Trans_id], [Amount], [Currency], [ExchangeRate], [CorrAmount],
         [SenderPhone], [RecipientPhone], [SenderPr], [RecipientPr],
         [Trans_Status], [SendDate], [Receivdate], [Trans_type])
```

or just use a regular nonclustered index?

Hope you can help me, thanks a lot.

Comment: I know that the table design is incorrect but the data in it is incorrect

Comment: Thanks for your response 
and Do you mean to create an index of names and another for phone numbers?

Comment: You wouldn't want an index on both columns, as you are not looking for a combination of names. You are looking for an OR, so that implies one index on sender, and another index on recipient.

Comment: Do you mean I need to create four separate indexes and Thank you very much for your response.

Comment: Yes, I would create 4 indexes, and let the query optimiser work out what to use for each query you submit. And I would also use standard simple create index statement, as that will give you 99% of what you need.

Comment: A **covering index** only really makes sense if you select *a few columns* and can include those in the index. You should **NOT** creating a covering index on **all** columns of the table - but then again, you should also **NOT** use `SELECT * ` in a production system any way - only select **those columns** (as an **explicit** list of columns) that you really need at any given time

Comment: thank you very much
You helped me a lot